# How to convert selected file input images into blob

Tags: javascript

I want to use a file input to select some images. In my HTML code, I have this

```
<input type="file" ref="file" name="images[]">
```

After the selection, I want to transform each selected image into a blob. How I can achieve this in my Vue app? I'm not sure if I need to use a file reader or if I need to simulate an ajax call to transform the image into a blob

Comment: a file inherits the blob class so a file is basically a blob already. you can treat the file as if it's a blob.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `FileRead` to read file data
then use `Blob` and `URL.createObjectURL` to create blob url.

```js
const fr = new FileReader()
const file = document.querySelector("input[name='images[]']").files[0]
fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
fr.onload = function() {
    // you can keep blob or save blob to another position
    const blob = new Blob([fr.result])

    // url for download
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob, {type: "image/png"});
    const a = document.createElement("a")
    a.href = url 
    a.download = "image"
    a.click()
}
```

Comment: I need to get back the file after it's converted into blob so the ObjectURL isn't the best solution. Why you've read the file as text?

Comment: I modified the code for image. But what do you mean that "get back the file"?

Comment: I mean that I need to preserve the blob data or data uri to use the image later. I'm storing it

Comment: using the filereader this way is pointless, a file inherits the blob class so a file is basically a blob already. the question is a bit unclear